# When will the velocity of oscillating particle become zero in simple harmonic motion?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

*This question came in the Jagannath University admission exam 13-14*

Q) In simple harmonic oscillation, the velocity of an oscillating particle becomes zero-

(a) when acceleration is maximum

(b) when displacement is minimum

(c) when displacement is maximum

(d) when acceleration is minimum

This seems like a bad question. Both (a) and (c) seem correct, but we can select only one option as the correct answer. Aren't both a and c correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that there is more than one answer here, and if it states that there is only *one* possible answer, then the question is poorly worded.

At maximum displacement in SHM, the velocity is indeed zero but the *force* (and therefore acceleration) is at a maximum directed toward the position of equilibrium. So (a).

At maximum displacement, the object undergoing SHM is momentarily at rest meaning again it must have zero velocity. So (c).

Answer (score 1):

What a nice exam. All answers are correct. Presuming we are talking about signed quantities and not their amplitude, which seems fair from the wording.

Say we start with maximum displacement at phase angle 0. Then at this point we also have minimum acceleration (maximum absolute value, but with a negative sign). And at phase angle $\pi$ we have minimum displacement (maximum absolute value, but with a negative sign) and maximum acceleration. And of course zero velocity at phase angle 0 or $\pi$.